# Google Sheets, Two Font Sizes One Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-macros

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of lines of data, coming from data validation lists.

Some of the data is highly relevant, therefore I would like it larger, some is useful but superfluous to most.

Different font size is fine. If anyone is an expert with though, different colours and format would be amazing

I would need the script to be dynamic in the sense that data to the left of the | is formatted one way and to the right of the | in another way.

[image]

Comment: @player0 It is possible in a single cell  even when doing it manually. You just need to select that part of the text and change font.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify the text style of the part of texts in a cell using Google Apps Script (From your tag of `google-sheets-macros`).
- You want to modify `CODE` of `NAME NAME | CODE`.

  - You don't want to modify the text style of `NAME NAME` +   + `|` +  .
  - You want to modify the text style of only `CODE`.
  - From `Different font size is fine. If anyone is an expert with though, different colours and format would be amazing`, you want to modify the font size and foreground color of the text. In this case, `format` you expect is the bold and italic?
- You want to keep the text style of `NAME NAME` of `NAME NAME | CODE`.

I think that above goal can be achieved using RichTextValue. In this answer, I would like to propose the sample script.

#### Sample situation:

This sample script supposes the sample situation that the value of `NAME NAME | CODE` are put in the column "A". So in order to test it, please prepare this situation.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, and set the sheet name.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
    const text = a.getText();
    const pos = text.indexOf("|");
    if (pos > -1) {
      const temp = a.getTextStyle(0, pos - 1);
      const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(5)
        .setForegroundColor("red")
        .setItalic(true)
        .setBold(true)
        .build();
      return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setTextStyle(0, pos - 1, temp)
        .setTextStyle(pos + 2, text.length, textStyle)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(a.getTextStyle()).build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Result:

When you run the above script, the text styles of column "A" are reformatted and the text style of `CODE` is modified, while the text style of `NAME NAME` of `NAME NAME | CODE` is not modified. And also, the text style of the cell without `|` is not modified. You can see the sample result at the following image.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is a simple sample. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

### Added:

When you want to convert the selected range, how about the following sample script? When you use this script, at first, please select the range and run this script. By this, the selected range is converted.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const select = ss.getSelection();
  const sheet = select.getActiveSheet();
  const range = select.getActiveRange();
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
    const text = a.getText();
    const pos = text.indexOf("|");
    if (pos > -1) {
      const temp = a.getTextStyle(0, pos - 1);
      const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(5)
        .setForegroundColor("red")
        .setItalic(true)
        .setBold(true)
        .build();
      return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setTextStyle(0, pos - 1, temp)
        .setTextStyle(pos + 2, text.length, textStyle)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(a.getTextStyle()).build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

- If you want to put the converted values to one right side of the column, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      range.offset(0, 1).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
    ```

Comment: seems to work great, 1 problem I am having is trying to apply it to more than 1 column, so if I replace a1:a with a1:c for example - I get the following:


Message details
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 3.

Comment: I guess is there a way to make the range dynamic by the cells actively selected?

Comment: @Christopher Brogan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't image your current script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. And also, I couldn't notice that you wanted to convert the selected range from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I also deeply apologize for this. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.