# Google sheets, Add text with different font sizes in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I saw this other question on here that is very similar to what I need, but I need it a little different and I don't know what I need to change to do this.

[Google Sheets, Two Font Sizes One Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836792/google-sheets-two-font-sizes-one-cell) < This is the link to the question.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
    const text = a.getText();
    const pos = text.indexOf("|");
    if (pos > -1) {
      const temp = a.getTextStyle(0, pos - 1);
      const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(5)
        .setForegroundColor("red")
        .setItalic(true)
        .setBold(true)
        .build();
      return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setTextStyle(0, pos - 1, temp)
        .setTextStyle(pos + 2, text.length, textStyle)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(a.getTextStyle()).build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

^This is the code that answered the question to "*Google Sheets, Two Font Sizes One Cell*"

this is what i need, (image below).

[image]

In the "Google Sheets, Two Font Sizes One Cell" they have a dynamic setup where `NAME NAME` in `as is` might have red text so `desired` `NAME NAME` will also have red text. I dont want this. I want to take only the Value of the `Input`. The `Output` needs to have a set font for the *value* and *suffix*. I need the `value` font size to be `15`. And I need the `suffix` font size to be `8` and `italic`.

I also need the *value* to be rounded. so say the value of "miles per gal" is `21.2021857923497` i need it rounded to `21.20`. The amount of zeros after the decimal show what i need it rounded to on the image above . But "miles driven" wont need to be rounded.

The "Input" is going to be from a list of logs from one sheet and the "Output" is going to be a put in a separate sheet. (the calulated values are formulas i made)

[image]
[image]

I want to clarify this because i asked a very similar question a while ago about this and someone said to just seperate the *value* and *suffix* into 2 cells. the reason i dont want to do this is because in the context of where the "Outputs" are going to be, it has awkward spacing that I dont like. (example below)

[image]

Sorry if im asking for alot, but it would be awesome if anyone could help.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not directly useful for your situation. About your question, I have a question. In your question, 3 images are shown. Can I ask you about the detail of each image? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your input and output situation from your question and your current issut. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike no worries. so the input is the (calculated values) that you see in the logs sheet (3rd image). so say I take the (cost per gal) on the first row of the logs. which is ($3.88) < that value would be an input. and the output is just adding a suffix of (per gal) and puting it on another sheet. it would be added to the home sheet on a format i made that you see on the last image on (same cell) so in this example the output would be ($3.88 per gal) as you see in the last image in same cell as ($3.38 per gal). If you need any more clarifying just ask. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that the 3rd image including "Different cells" and "Same Cells" is the sample input situation. In that case, can you provide the sample output situation using this sample input situation? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the sample script to search in the target cell for a blank space rather than a "|", then you can address the value and suffix portions easily:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
    const text = a.getText();
    const pos = text.indexOf(" ");
    if (pos > -1) {
      const suffixStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(8)
        .setItalic(true)
        .build();
      const valueStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(15)
        .build();
      return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setTextStyle(0, pos, valueStyle)
        .setTextStyle(pos, text.length, suffixStyle)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(a.getTextStyle()).build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

Comment: sorry for being confusing. but thank you for doing this. i think ill be able to build off of this. but i just realized i might need something else.