# google sheets, 2 font type name in 1 cell with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, fonts, google-sheets-formula, google-webfonts

Part of text with font;
**libre barcode 39 extended**
and another part of the text;
**Arial** in a cell (google sheets).

=if(AA3="","",CONCATENATE("*",W3,"*",char(10),AC3,"،",AB3))

This is my formula.

I found [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836792/google-sheets-two-font-sizes-one-cell). The script changes the font size.
The first problem is, after running, my formula will be converted into text.
Is there a way to not change the formula to the text?
And the second question, how to change the type of the font other than the font size (line 14)?

---

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "RC/12";  // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("W3:W" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
    const text = a.getText();
    const pos = text.indexOf("|");
    if (pos > -1) {
      const temp = a.getTextStyle(0, pos - 1);
      const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(8)
        .setFont.Name = ("calabri")
        .setForegroundColor("Red")
        .setItalic(false)
        .setBold(false)
        .build();
      return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setTextStyle(0, pos - 1, temp)
        .setTextStyle(pos + 2, text.length, textStyle)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(a.getTextStyle()).build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

If there is an idea, please provide it.
Thanks.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Part of text with font; libre barcode 39 extended and another part of the text; Arial in a cell (google sheets).`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Sorry for the incomplete explanation!

My question is:
Is there a way to put text in a cell with two font types?
The text source is from functions and is not typed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Is there a way to put text in a cell with two font types? The text source is from functions and is not typed.`, in this case, in the current stage, the text style of the cell text from the formula cannot be set as part of the text, while the text style of the whole cell text from the formula can be set as the specific font. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this.